# Подскажите литературу для клиент-серверного приложения, и какую БД лучше использовать?

Tags: клиент-сервер, delphi-7

*Досталась мне задача на курсовую: БД колледжа ещё и клиент-серверная.*

Подскажите литературу для данной задачи, какую БД лучше использовать, какую СУБД.

Comment: Начать стоит с понимания, чем "БД" отличается от "СУБД". БД вам надо сделать, а СУБД вы же должны были проходить хоть какую-то? Иначе как вам задания дают?

Comment: Дело в том,что мне дали ,так сказать "спец.задание".Остальным на локальных ПК.

Comment: БД сначала думал делать на paradox 7,а сейчас засомневался,что его кроме interBase,что-то ещё поддерживает.

Comment: А на interBase нежелательно делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используете Delphi 7 (судя по метке, так и есть) ищите книги Фаронова и Архангельского.

СУБД лучше согласовать с руководителем курсового.

Comment: Delphi 7 уже безумное старье .. лучше перейти хотя бы на XE5 или выше.

Comment: @Kromster, это же курсовая. Многие преподы до сих пор учат молодёжь на TP 7 и Turbo C.

Comment: Вероятно да, но если не предлагать переходить на новое, то так все и останется )

Comment: Кстати,нам разрешают использовать новые  Delphi.